# Plotly add_hline() doesn't work with simple_white template

Tags: plotly

I was attempting to add a horizontal line to a Plotly graph using Plotly's add_hline().  It works perfectly fine so long as I do not use the simple_white template.  The MWE is here:

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.iris()
fig = px.scatter(df, x="petal_length", y="petal_width")
fig.add_hline(y=0.9, line_dash='dash', line_color='Red')
fig.update_layout(width=400, height=400,
                  # template='simple_white'
                  )
fig.show()
```

Without the template='simple_white' line, the add_hline() works as expected.  With that template though, and with no other changes, the plot is the same but without the horizontal line.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 6):

I can't say *why* this happens, but you can get around it by explicitly specifying `line_width` and `opacity` for the horizontal line, without messing with the template:

```
fig.add_hline(y=0.9, opacity=1, line_width=2, line_dash='dash', line_color='Red')
```

If you only specify line width, the line looks washed out, possibly some of the themes (`seaborn` and `ggplot2` in addition to `plotly_white`) change these two parameters?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why this occurs, but most likely the `simple_white` template renders over the annotation, or the background color supercedes the annotation.

Regardless of the reason, you can recreate the `simple_white` template by setting the plot background color to be white, then make the axes black, and add the tickmarks on the outside.

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.iris()
fig = px.scatter(df, x="petal_length", y="petal_width")
fig.add_hline(y=0.9, line_dash='dash', line_color='Red')
fig.update_layout(
    width=400, 
    height=400,
    plot_bgcolor="white",
    xaxis=dict(linecolor="black"),
    yaxis=dict(linecolor="black")
    # template='simple_white'
    )
fig.update_xaxes(ticks="outside")
fig.update_yaxes(ticks="outside")
fig.show()
```

[image]